# Login with expire date

Tags: laravel, authentication, credentials

I have an expire_date in my `User` model and I want to check when login. I write about active user in credentials method like this:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request) {
          return array_merge(
             $request->only($this->username(), 'password'),
             ['status' => 1]
          );
}
```

but, it add equal condition only but i want add `>= date('Y-m-d')` in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the laravel documentation we can add custom conditions to `Auth::attempt` but only for equality checks.
In this case the only option would be to override the `login` method in the `LoginController` (method is defined in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait) and add custom check just before sending the login response.

```
// for check expire date
$user = (new User())->where('email', $request->email)->get();
if ($user[0]->expire_date < date('Y-m-d')) {
   return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```